# Reusing Smarty replace modifier in multiple templates

Tags: smarty2

I’m finding that I’m reusing the same replace modifier in multiple places around my Smarty template files to replace some non-alphanumeric characters.

An example:

```
{markdown text=$star.description|replace:'’':'&rsquo;'|replace:'‘':'&lsquo;'|replace:'“':'&ldquo;'|replace:'”':'&rdquo;'|replace:' – ':' &mdash; '|replace:' — ':' &mdash; '|replace:'…':'&hellip;'|replace:'é':'&eacute;'}
```

Ideally, I should keep that list of replace phrases in one place and reference that whenever I need to, but I can’t find the right way to do that in Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modifier in smarty so then you can call it this way (if i.e. you named it "cleantext"):

```
{markdown text=$star.description|cleantext}
```

read more about creating your own modifiers at http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl

Comment: Okay, I see, that’s helpful thanks. I wasn’t sure which avenue to pursue.